# Best way to affix downspout to vinyl sided house?

Tags: gutters, vinyl-siding, downspout

I am seriously thinking of getting a 1000 gallon tank to divert rain water for use in the garden in the dry summer months when water is most expensive where I live. I order to place the tank somewhere near a downspout and out of the way, I will have to reroute a downspout from its current straight down location to add in two elbows to divert it about 10 feet left to go where the tank needs to be.

So my question is what is the best way to affix the downspout to a vinyl sided house while keeping the siding from buckling and moisture out from where the screw will penetrate the siding and moisture membrane into the sheathing.

Comment: You are placing the gutter on the siding, and not on the overhang? There are different materials in each location. If you are at the roof edge, fastening can be different than on the wall. A picture would help understand where you plan to set it. Perhaps you mean downspout fastening and not gutter?

Comment: You are correct, I meant downspout. I changed the title and text. Not sure why I fixated on gutter when I do know the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, I'd use nothing. The problem is if you ever *remove* the screw, then the hole needs to be filled. Mount the bracket high-up, tucked under a lap, so *you* don't buckle the siding while installing it. Check both ends of the siding for play first. Affixed in the middle with room on both sides, it should be fine. Use screws with a fully threaded shank; you're only going into plywood. They sell [gasketed screws](http://forums2.gardenweb.com/forums/load/strucs/msg1219470810308.html?3) if you want to go nuts:

[image]